# Are 'vectors' vectors?

Tags: vector-spaces, definition

Let us say I have a 'vector' $\vec v$ for which I can do the following operation on $A\vec v$ where $A$ is a matrix. Now most people (i think) would say that $\vec v \in R^n$ however $\vec v$ is not a an $n$-tuple, it can't be since matrices can't act on tuples and therefore $\vec v$ is not in $R^n$. Does this mean $\vec v$ is not a vector in terms of been an element of a vector space?

(I agree that there is an isomorphism between the vector which you use a matrix on and n-tuples)

Comment: Why can't matrices act on tuples?

Comment: @FredrikMeyer I don't know, but I was told this, I think the reason is that n-tuples are basis independent, matrices are basis dependent and must act on an object that is also basis dependent and therefore cannot act on n-tuples

Comment: Hey, for vector spaces you need multiplication by a scalar, not a matrix! Check the definitions!

Comment: @brick I know, there is nothing in my question that indicates otherwise (I don't think)

Comment: @Rahul Sorry, I am saying that n-tuples are elements of $R^n$, I have explained why I said matrices can't act on n-tuples above and for (3) I am not saying this either, I know that e.g. a function can be in a vector space

Comment: I think the difference between $\vec v \in \mathbb R^n$ is that the entries of $\vec v$ form a n-tupel, but $\vec v$ gets its vector nature by its unit vectors ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the tuple $\vec{x}=(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ is not really different from the coordinates of  $\vec{x}$ relative to the canonical basis of $R^n$ formed by the element $e_1 =(1,0, \dots, 0)$, $e_2= (0,1, 0, \dots, 0)$ and so on.

Absent any indication to the contrary one would usually assume that the matirx is meant with respect to the canonical basis and everything is fine.

It is however true that in a strict sense the operation of a matrix on the elements of a vector space only really makes sense when an ordered basis is given (explicitly or implicitly).

There might also be a second issue, if one is very strict, namely, that of rows versus columns. However, it seems this is not the current convern.

Comment: when we represent a coordinate vector is that coordinate vector an n-tuple or some other distinct object,

Comment: This depends on your convention. In the case you give things are a bit confusing since many people actually will consider the coordinates precisely as an $n$-tuple; it seems this is what Rahul os getting at. (Your question would be thus more transparent would you take any other vectorspace but $R^n$. Where it would be clearer that you first have to choose a basis.) There are howver people that do distinguish between $R^n$ and the coordinates, since they will consider the collection of coordinates as $n\times 1$ matrices.